# Migrating to Azure CLU services from soon to be deprecated LUIS - recognizing a 'gather number' intent

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding, language-studio

The LUIS way of doing things, we were able to specify a 'pattern' and get the intents with 100% confidence.  And we are trying to get to the same confidence level with the new CLU service.  We migrated to CLU from LUIS - but the 'patterns' data got lost in migration as they are not supported in the CLU services.

We are trying to achieve the same with the new CLU service, with a project that would model a 'gather any number' intent.

Attached is a JSON file of the project the we have been trying out with.  Trying to get the model to recognize the intent with 100% confidence.  But it is not recognizing the intent correctly.

Our goal is to recognize any of the following phrases as a 'gather_number' intent with 100% confidence.
The entity value is recognized with 100% accuracy fine.  But the intent is not as shown in the 'Actual intent confidence' below.

Any thoughts on what could be done for training the model to get to 100% in all scenarios for 'Actual intent confidence'?

With CLU, here are the findings:

| Input | Intent | myNumber entity value | Expected Intent Confidence | Actual intent confidence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | gather_number | 1 | 100% | 67.33% |
| 100 | gather_number | 100 | 100% | 100% |
| its 100 | gather_number | 100 | 100% | 100% |
| its 3212.44 | gather_number | 3212.44 | 100% | 65.18% |
| willing to give 383.22 | gather_number | 383.22 | 100% | 62.24% |
| dummy text | None | No entities predicted | 100% | 67.30% |
| blah | None | No entities predicted | 100% | 100% |
| 200 may be | None | No entities predicted | 100% | 76.86% |

Here is the exported CLU project JSON:

```html
{
    "projectFileVersion": "2022-10-01-preview",
    "stringIndexType": "Utf16CodeUnit",
    "metadata": {
        "projectKind": "Conversation",
        "settings": {
            "confidenceThreshold": 0
        },
        "projectName": "TestNumbers",
        "multilingual": false,
        "description": "Testing any number",
        "language": "en-us"
    },
    "assets": {
        "projectKind": "Conversation",
        "intents": [
            {
                "category": "None"
            },
            {
                "category": "gather_number"
            }
        ],
        "entities": [
            {
                "category": "mynumber",
                "compositionSetting": "combineComponents",
                "prebuilts": [
                    {
                        "category": "Quantity.Number"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "utterances": [
            {
                "text": "oh k 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "take 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "100 now 200 later",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "only 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "100 only",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [
                    {
                        "category": "mynumber",
                        "offset": 0,
                        "length": 3
                    }
                ],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "this time 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "no 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "yes 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "for now 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "great 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "its 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "it is 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "ok 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "how about 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "got to pay 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            },
            {
                "text": "my number is 100",
                "language": "en-us",
                "intent": "gather_number",
                "entities": [],
                "dataset": "Train"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```